# Best way to combine results of two select statements without returning an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get one set of unique users from querying two different tables. For example, let's say I want to find the set of unique pet owners. Some owners own dogs, some own cats- I want the number of owners who own a dog or a cat or both.

I know one solution is

```
dog_owners = Dog.joins(:owner).select(:owner_id).distinct
cat_owners = Cat.joins(:owner).select(:owner_id).distinct
combined_owners = dog_owners + cat_owners
unique_owners = combined_owners.uniq{|x| x.owner_id}
unique_owners.count
```

Is there a way to do this where I wouldn't have to use the `uniq` call, and could use `distinct` instead? Because the `+` operator returns an Array, I am not able to use `distinct` here.

Comment: I'm just stabbing in the dark, but have you tried the `&` operator instead of the `+` operator?

Answer (score 2):

Can you go the other way around?

```
Owner
   .left_outer_joins(:dogs, :cats)
   .where("dogs.owner_id IS NOT NULL OR cats.owner_id IS NOT NULL")
   .distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

I think gabrielhilal's answer is better. I'm just putting it here for anyone who would probably have same requirements as OP but with needed flexibility in the conditions.

```
owners = Owner.where(
  id: Dog.joins(:owner).select(:owner_id)
).or(
  Owner.where(
    id: Cat.joins(:owner).select(:owner_id)
  )
)
```